# How to run Weylus on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, ipad

*(replicated from a post asked by me on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ipad/comments/qb5hdb/how_to_run_weylus_on_windows_10/))*

Hi,

So I learned about [Weylus](https://github.com/H-M-H/Weylus) when researching ways to turn my iPad into nothing short of an intuos.

I tried running Weylus on my pc but this is what happens-

[image]
Firstly, that WARN Configuration message didn't come a while ago (Weylus didn't work even then).

Secondly, as seen in screenshots, there is no qr code and the "Connect your tablet to" shows the template link, not my IP address.

I tried opening the tcp ports(1701 and 9001) but nothing changed. Also, there is little to no info about running weylus on Windows (Linux support is available though).

So, has anyone run Weylus on windows and could guide me in doing so?

Thanks

*(P.S. Could anyone also confirm that whether weylus can be used to extend the ipad as a second screen and, if yes, how to do so?)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Weylus developer has answered to the same problem in the
redit post
[Weylus - Use your Tablet as Graphic Tablet/Touch Screen for your Computer (Open Source)](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/msbxr6/dev_weylus_use_your_tablet_as_graphic_tablettouch/):

> Looks like you are running Windows, I do not run Windows personally and a video probably wouldn't be too helpful then. It looks like binding on `0.0.0.0` does not work for some reason. You can try replacing `0.0.0.0` in the bind address field with the actual IP address of your computer. You can obtain it by running `ipconfig` with `cmd.exe` (just open cmd.exe and type ipconfig then press enter and it will tell you your IP address).

I'm not running Weylus so cannot test the above advice
(or find where are you supposed to set the IP address).

Comment: Works like a charm....Thanks a ton for this